# Translation of "The free man"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What would be the correct translation of "the free man"? A human which is free, not a slave to others.

Google translate suggests "liberorum" but I have no way of verifying.

Answer (score 3):

*līber* (adjective used substantively). What's the sentence as that might change the case?

Note it also means 'children' in the plural (*i.e.* people free from the constraints of adulthood). *liberorum* is the genitive plural (though L&S says *liberum* is common too) https://logeion.uchicago.edu/liber

'Freedman' (*i.e.* an ex-slave) is *libertus, -i*

https://logeion.uchicago.edu/libertus